# Regex to match all of a set except certain ones

Tags: regex

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find it (or know the proper wording to search for)

Basically I want a regex that matches all non-alphanumeric except hyphens.  So basically match \W+ except exclude '-'  I'm not sure how to exclude specific ones from a premade set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\W` is a shorthand for `[^\w]`. So:

```
[^\w-]+
```

A bit of background:

- `[…]` defines a set
- `[^…]` negates a set
- Generally, every `\v` (smallcase) set is negated by a `\V` (uppercase) where V is any letter that defines a set.
- for international characters, you may want to look into `[[:alpha:]]` and `[[:alnum:]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
[^\w-]+
```

will do just that. Match any characters not in the `\w` set except hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]
```

or

```
[^\w-]
```

to match a single non-hyphen, non-alphanumeric. To match one or more of then prefix with a `+`

Comment: Underscore is missing (as well as lots of accented characters if his regex flavor considers characters like ä, ß  or à to be part of `\w`)...

Answer (score 0):

In Java7 or above, you need to prepend the `(?U)` to match all locale specific characters. e.g.

```
(?U)[^\w-]
```

In a Java string (you need to escape `\` character with another one):

```
(?U)[^\\w-]
```