# Regexp match sequence that NOT contains list of words (.NET)

Tags: .net, regex

Source text for search:

```
/russia/moscow-region/moscow/mitino_m
/russia/moscow-region/moscow/planernaya_m
/russia/moscow-region/outside
/russia/moscow-region/moscow/otradnoe_m
/russia/moscow-region/outside/podol-sk
/russia/moscow-region/foreign/mexico
/russia/moscow-region/moscow
/russia/moscow-region/abrakadabra/u-lalala
/russia/moscow-region/outside/himki
/russia/moscow-region/moscow/preobrajenskaya_pl_m
```

Regexp is here:

```
russia/moscow-region/(moscow|outside).*$
```

you can see results right here: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=7f93ce7f

I need to inverse this expression to match all values that NOT contains words `moscow, outside` after "russia/moscow-region/" string value. How to change it?

Comment: Duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820930/regex-how-to-exclude-single-word) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683718/how-to-exclude-a-string) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854817/regex-match-words-except-these) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532008/regex-to-match-all-of-a-set-except-certain-ones) ...

Comment: Wow.. I really should check that before I answer people :(

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Group it as NOT:

```
russia/moscow-region/(?!(moscow|outside)).*
```

Comment: Is this possible without a negative lookahead?  My regex implementation does not support it.